# Would zombies be all bald?

Tags: zombies, hair

all hair grows, dies, is replaced > process repeats over and over again for the rest of your life unless you are of European or North African descent, then at some point you'll grow bald spots instead of more hair.

But zombies do not regenerate so easily.

- Dead zombies powered by magic usually don't regenerate at all, so would those zombies just go all bald within a few weeks?
- Parasite zombies are just walking carcasses, no regeneration still

Would that mean that in a zombie apocalypse you'd just see bald marches all around the globe?

Comment: by the time the hair has worn away the skin will be gone as well. Zombies won't last all that long because everything is taking damage.

Comment: If you allow for one impossible thing (zombies) why do you question a tiny little detail of that impossibility (hair)?

Comment: Zombies inherently don't make any sense. They're fiction. To even approach a sensible answer, you need to specify what flavor of zombie you are talking about: are these magic zombies? fungal zombies? something else? The basic problem is that if you approach zombies with anything near a "realistic" lens (as you are in asking about hair loss), the whole concept breaks down because you need to start considering factors like "energy" or "how zombies move".

Comment: I don't often VTC:Opinion-Based, but that's all this is: opinion-based. It's your magic and your rules. If you want to conclude that the hair falls out after a few weeks, then you're forced to ask, "will the skin fall off? teeth fall out?" etc. If the hair falls out but the skin doesn't fall off, that's your rule for your zombies. You're asking us this question as if there's a definitive, objective answer when it's 100% based on the rules of your magic system and we're just slinging thoughts at you. That's prohibited by the [help/dont-ask].

Comment: You can justify hair if you want, or have different kinds of zombies. "quick-prep" zombies take a fresh corpse that decays rapidly(and have hair), while "durable" zombies undergo a process like making leather and mummification, to assure joint flexibility, slow decay and toughness. But they're bald.

Comment: @VLAZ zombies isn't an impossibility since we have rhabies which is pretty much a zombie virus that kills you before it has time to spread.... But still a very real and very possible "zombie" virus, also many zombie parasytes for other animals and zombie fungi....

Comment: @Dragongeek idem as above

Comment: "[Keratin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratin) is the key structural material making up scales, hair, nails, feathers, horns, claws, hooves, **and the outer layer of skin** among vertebrates." - they still have hair or they got no skin. So, Fallout got it right: no hair, losing skin *fast*, and there's a tree budding out of their shoulder. - *Would they still have their 'junk'?* Clothesless, [anatomically correct zombies](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/37348) that are trying to bite you; you ain't looking at their bald head....

Comment: @Xenophile While there are some """real""" zombie viruses (mostly for less complex creatures), the fundamental problem is that organisms need energy to move, and unlike simpler creatures, humans are fantastically complex. Unless you go in a "smart zombies" direction where zombies are just normal people who enjoy suddenly enjoy killing, but still go to their 9-5 jobs, zombies would not be a threat as they would be too stupid to open doors, too uncoordinated to walk, and all starve within a couple days. Walking "undead" is just ludicrous without magic, because a corpse is definitionally "broken"

Comment: @Dragongeek still how does that invalidate a question about hair falling off deald people? remove the zombie part and it's a perfectly normal question

Comment: @JBH how is this question opinion based. I just assumed it asks if the hair of corpses falls out or not. It doesn't seem to have to do anything with magic besides setting up the premise.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock democracy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Look at regular dead bodies

Does hair fall out on regular dead bodies? Answer: not much. It actually keeps growing for a short time, before everything shuts down - and then whatever hair is still there, stays there. If you're using dead bodies as a model for how zombies will look, that's probably where you want to go.

Of course the fact that zombies are still moving around would tend to suggest that blood is back flowing again somehow. It's up to you how you think that'll affect everything else.

Comment: Honestly I've never seen a dead person

Comment: Pretty sure hair doesn't grow after death, it just appears longer because the skin retracts. Same with fingernails.

Answer (score 7):

### Magic zombies *do* regenerate!

I guess this is technically a frame challenge.

Magic zombies very often do regenerate. Sometimes the story even makes it explicit. But more often what you'll see is a kind of zombie that is simultaneously disintegrating at a rapid pace, yet maintaining the same overall level of physical repair and gruesomeness. It is never explained, but readers/audiences generally accept it because it's a very helpful concession to make to a genre that would otherwise run aground very quickly on accurate but banal grounds.

It's like when Spielberg plays tricks with editing to make the boulder chasing Indiana Jones somehow always be on his heels and accelerating but magically never quite catching up to him. If you're keeping score at home, you'll recognize that the boulder is being handicapped whenever it's off-camera, but you'll also realize that it makes the movie more fun.

Comment: i don't think you can generally say zombies do regenerate as it the depends on the setting. I think more often than not movies or other media don't care about zombie decomposition rates. I mean generally a Zombie that rooted naturally would probably stop being a threat after a year in normal conditions. Though i admit that zombies either having slowed decomposition or slight regeneration is a logical conclusion to make. Otherwise how would you explain zombies still walking around even decades after the initial outbreak.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock a year? Without any kind of new cell production I'd give them a week at most. After that a number of cells with a regeneration cycle of a few days should have fried enough of the intestines and blood.

Comment: @DonQuiKong i was generally talking how long they would remain mobile. Ofcourse with magic i generally regard the functioning of organic structures. I was just thinking how long there would be still enough skin left that the zombie doesn't fall apart.

Comment: I think it's not that zombies magically regenerate so much as they get replaced by newer (freshly recruited) zombies on a regular basis.  The zombies that have finally deteriorated into immobility don't get a lot of screen time.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes and No**

It depends on how you want to look at it and from what timespan you look at the topic. By the way zombies do play a big role in my world as well so thank you for reminding me to consider something like this.

- **Generally No:** Hair actually rots a lot slower than other tissues like skin. So i would more worry about how this decomposes.
- **Eventually Yes:** Hair is attached to the deeper layers of our skin. So eventually when the skin rots away the hair will also fall out. So your zombie would eventually go balder and balder but when he is finally bald... Well there would not be a lot of skin left anyway.
- **Conclusion:** So generally yes your zombies have definitely hair even if it doesn't regrow. They would lose ot overtime of course but when they get really bald there would not a lot soft tissue left anyways. And while i do not know your magic a Zombie might become unusable by then...if they don't turn into Skeletons that is.

*Note:English is not my primary language so please excuse any grammar or spelling errors.*

Answer (score 3):

The walkers.. the first thing that gives, is the rotting entrails. They intestines, they just drop right through the sphincter into there trousers - after the first 50 miles on average.

Whatever keeps the blood liquid enough, to support that cursed half-life, it cant keep the blood in, it doesn't clog. So they loose the 6 liter lease on a half-life they had.

Then it gets dark fast. Without the blood, the muscles use up all ATP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigor_mortis#Physiology sets in.They become stiff as a stick-insect. But most important- the already near-dead brain, finally fails. The last instinct is hunger.. so they claw there own flesh, devouring what they can still reach. There own Fingers, fat tissue, the remaining parts in the body cavity.

The eyesight has died weeks ago, but the hearing was still there + some basic wiring for touch and position. Now the last telephoneline is cut.
What is left, will shiver and spasm for up to 3 days.
If the wild boars give it that much time.
They leave the bones - and the hair.